# IBM Bluemix SSL Intermediate Certificate

Tags: ssl, ibm-cloud

I seem to be having a problem with uploading a wildcard go daddy ssl certificate in the domains section in IBM Bluemix. If I upload without the intermediate certificate it seems to upload fine. But with it it times out (with error BXNUI0068E: The operation on the client timed out. Try again later.) and the upload is incomplete.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the zip file from GoDaddy has a corrupted intermediate certificate.

After talking with @carlosTweets he suggested it seemed like the zipped certificates were corrupt. Surely enough compared the md5 for the zipped certificate vs the one from the repository below, both were different.

Get the proper one from their repo. Link below

https://certs.godaddy.com/repository

make sure to download the certificate with the name

"GoDaddy Certificate Bundles - G2 With Cross to G1, includes Root"